# How to exclude certain URI from Apache mod_rewrite (Apache 2.2) in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have .htaccess file that is successfully redirecting requests based on detecting incoming URI and prefixing with "index.php" for Codeigniter, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm now just building custom Apache modules, and I need to exclude any URI request to that module.  My httpd.conf will show something like:

```
LoadModule my_module        modules/libmod_my.so
<Location /mymodule>
    SetHandler mod_my-handler
</Location>
```

This should work fine, but the .htaccess rule is catching any request to /mymodule and turning it into  /index.php/mymodule

The .htaccess rules do successfully bypass any request to a valid file (graphics, css, js, etc.).

What is the best way to amend the .htaccess to also have it bypass any request like this:

http://localhost/mymodule/function

so that any request to /mymodule is excluded from being modified?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  There isn't anything in the request for "modules" here.  That's just the location where the .so file lives and is referenced in the LoadModule directive in httpd.conf   Wouldn't this be more appropriate to look at the REQUEST_URI and see if it starts with "mymodule"?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude anything starting with `mymodule`, add another condition in front of the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mymodule
```

---

Another approach (although I haven't tried this yet) could be to switch off `mod_rewrite` inside the `Location` directive

```
<Location /mymodule>
    SetHandler mod_my-handler
    RewriteEngine off
</Location>
```